# Question with 60 revisions without real change

Tags: support, suggested-edits, gaming-the-system

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14040027/revisions). It has 60 revisions, the same user adding and removing the same line of text.

I noticed it because the OP has 51 edit reviews, of the same post. So probably something went wrong in the database.

Comment: The timestamps differ—I would suspect something else is going on here (possibly one user trying to get his second account rep from suggested edits?)

Comment: I say the user found a way to re-submit the same two suggestions over and over again, gaming the system. Badge harvesting!

Comment: Together with some sock puppetry; most edits have been approved by one 'Alligator', the OP of the question in fact.

Comment: Soo dumb of him o.O

Comment: There is no rollback involved as far as I can tell, just gaming the system.

Comment: Hmm.. think you also found a nice bug: 12 edits (no matter who made them) should convert a post to Community Wiki however in this case it's still not CW probably because *suggested edits* are not counted.

Comment: Oh good ***gawd***.

Comment: Aw man, *this guy*.  He "*reported me to SO*" for *allegedly* downvoting [one of his horrible (deleted) questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14036586/168868).  That was fun.

Comment: I've contacted those that needed to be contacted privately and dealt with what needed to be dealt with. Thanks for shining a light on this. Of all the ways to game the system, _this one_ never crossed my mind.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I think for CW you need a certain number of different authors.

Comment: @MartijnPieters nope, I'm 99.999% sure that 12 edits of OP also makes it CW.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740) five different users, or 10 edits *by the original owner*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, for some reason always thought 10 edits as a "total limit" of edits. So looks like two, three or four users can edit a post hundreds of times without making it CW.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is case of sock-puppetry and badge harvesting. The OP has approved most of the suggested edits, and they are all separate.

Flag the post for moderator attention, I certainly will.

Comment: Might also be just two friends, but this is obviously bad behavior and they both should be warned and suspended if they keep doing it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I reported it as such ("sockpuppet or friends"); but the definition of a sock puppet doesn't exclude two friends boosting one another. :-)